# Python celery connect through ssl

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, rabbitmq, celery

I have been trying to connect to a RabbitMQ (it was created from AWS Messaging Service if it matters) instance via celery 5.0.5. The connection link starts as follows `amqps://user:password@..../`. I receive the following error when running my python script:

```
consumer: Cannot connect to amqps://sessionstackadmin:**@b-0482d011-0cca-40bd-968e-c19d6c85e2a9.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:5671//: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
```

I am running the script from a docker container with `python 3.6.12`. The docker container has access to the endpoint (at least it can telnet to it). I have the feeling that the python process does not respect the distro certificate chain and it just fails verifying the certificate.

Comment: I just run into the same problem, though I'm using celery from master.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it! Celery is using Kombu, which is using py-amqp and it happens that the latest version [5.0.3 from Jan 19](https://pypi.org/project/amqp/#history) is broken.

My GH ticket https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/issues/349

Solution: add `amqp==5.0.2` as a hard dependency in your project requirements.

Fix at: `git+git://github.com/celery/py-amqp.git@0b8a832d32179d33152d886acd6f081f25ea4bf2`

Comment: Sadly this did not resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Oh my God! I've spent an eternity trying to fix this with different configurations and it appears there even wasn't anything wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving the workaround that "fixes" this. For some reason the `kombu` library when trying to handle ssl connections does not respect the default CA certs coming with your distribution. This is basically handled by https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context which the library does not use. Sadly it does not allow to pass in a custom `SSLContext` but only a set of options that will be later passed down to the context. One such options is [broker_use_ssl](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v5.0.5/userguide/configuration.html#broker-use-ssl). By settings it to `{'ca_certs': '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}` it will respect the CA certs from the distribution (keep in mind that I am using an ubuntu/debian based image and the CA certs configuration file resides there, if you are using another distro check out the proper location for your CA certs).

Comment: It looks exactly like the change from 5.0.3 https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/compare/v5.0.2...v5.0.3#diff-d15f5a21209365d247f6eb7de177b9130a81b2f9d7cc5dd6a16ebad28c7839f3L40-L44

Comment: Added link with fix in initial answer. Probably will be released soon as 5.0.4